# Cooccurrence in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, self-join

I am familiar with relational database such as MySQL. Recently I'm working on project that use MongoDb to stock 100,000 Documents. The structure of these Docs is as such:

```
    {
      "_id" : "1",
      "abstract" : "In this book, we present ....",
      "doi" : "xxxx/xxxxxx",
      "authors" : [ 
                   "Davis, a", 
                   "louis, X", 
                   "CUI, Li", 
                   "FANG, Y"
                    ]
      }
```

I would like to extract the cooccurrence matrix or cooccurrence value of all possible combination of authors (only pairs). the expected output is:

```
{ [auth1 , auth2 : 5 ] [auth1, auth3 : 1] [auth2, auth8 : 9]....}
```

which means that auth1 and auth2 collaborate 5 times (in 5 books) auth2 and auth8 collaborate 9 times...

In relation database, possible solution could be:
in a table auth-book for example:

```
    INSERT INTO auth-book (id_book, id_auth) VALUES
              (1, 'auth1'),
              (1, 'auth2'),
              (1, 'auth3'),
              (2, 'auth1'),
              (2, 'auth5'),
              (2, 'auth87'),
              (2, 'auth2')...
```

the query that calculate cooccurrence or collaboration of authors is:

```
     SELECT   a.id_auth a, b.id_auth b, COUNT(*) cnt
     FROM     auth-book a JOIN auth-booke b ON b.id_book= a.id_book AND   .id_auth > a.id_auth
     GROUP BY a.id_auth, b.id_auth
```

output: [auth1 auth2 => 2][auth1 auth3 => 1][auth2 auth3 => 1]... etc.

I have no idea how to implement such a query in mongodb

Comment: All possible combos or pairs?   That SQL statement will only get pairs, yes?

Comment: yes, only pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wee bit scary but it seems to work.  Basically, we `$lookup` against ourselves and leverage the fact that lookup of a string into an array of strings is an implicit `$in`-like operation.

```
 db.foo.aggregate([
 // Create single deduped list of authors:
 {$unwind: "$authors"}
 ,{$group: {_id:null, uu: {$addToSet: "$authors"} }}

 // Now unwind and go lookup into the authors array in the same collection.  If $uu
 // appears anywhere in the authors array, it is a match.
 ,{$unwind: "$uu"}
 ,{$lookup: { from: "foo", localField: "uu", foreignField: "authors", as: "X"}}

 // OK, lots of material in the pipe here.  Brace for a double unwind -- but
 // in this data domain it is probably OK because not every book has the same
 // set of authors, which will attenuate the result $lookup above.
 ,{$unwind: "$X"}
 ,{$unwind: "$X.authors"}

 // The data is starting to be clear here.  But we see two things: 
 // self-matching (author1->author1) and pairs of inverses
 // (author1->author2 / author2->author1).  We don't need self matches and we
 // only need "one side" of the inverses.   So... let's do a strcasecmp
 // on them.  0 means the same so that's out.  So pick 1 or -1 to get one side
 // of the pair; doesn't really matter!  This is why the OP has b.id_auth > a.id_auth
 // in the SQL equivalent: to eliminate self match and one side of inverses.
 ,{$addFields: {q: {$strcasecmp: ["$uu", "$X.authors"] }} }
 ,{$match: {q: 1}}  

 // And now group!
 ,{$group: {_id: {a: "$uu", b: "$X.authors"}, n: {$sum:1}}}
            ]);
```

Comment: Wow, this works good. It takes time but works good. Just one more thing How can i run this query on only few documents identified by their _id. I mean the _id exist in array of id example run this query on documents that have _id in array A=(16,12,15,177,19988,...)

Comment: I don't know what machinery you have but this solution trades a stage in the pipeline for more material that must be filtered, specifically the self matches.   Can post that on request.  On my Mac it was so close in perf that I went for the simpler option.
OK -- is that array of _id for the first stage only (i.e. in lieu of the authors) or what is being looked up against?
And don't by shy about hitting +1 on the solution.

Comment: I did hit +1 on the solution but it seems that i dont have enough reputation to vote publicly ( it is recorded any way). about the array of _id, this is for selecting in the first place the document that should be analysed with your query. I tried adding {$match:{'_id': {'$in' : ['1', '22', ...]}}} before the first unwind, is this right ? thank you again

Comment: no, my solution doesnt work. In fact i want to preselect the documents that should be analysed by your query and that their _id exist in predefined array of ids

Comment: Well, a $match before the first unwind should cut down the number of authors that make it into the self-$lookup.   Are you trying to limit the output of that $lookup, i.e. given author A, $lookup finds him in 100 docs but you want to narrow that to just docs with _id 1, 22, etc.?  I am sorry but I am still not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes exactly, for example Given an author A $lookup finds him in 100 docs and i just want to narrow that to docs with _id 1,22,3,...

Comment: Ahhhhh.   You need the new pipeline feature in $lookup in the just-released version 3.6.   Basically, the pipeline is evaluated with each lookup and it would allow you to easily say $match: {_id: {$in: [1,22]}}

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for but this "works."   The challenge is creating the pairs list which is what the self join in SQL is doing.   Moving the pairing out of the query also means it is easier later to change from pairs to triples to whatever because the `find()` uses the `$all` function to ensure a match for any number of items.

```
c=db.foo.aggregate([
// Create single deduped list of authors:
{$unwind: "$authors"}
,{$group: {_id:null, uu: {$addToSet: "$authors"} }}
            ]);

doc = c.next(); // Get single doc output from above
ulist = doc['uu'];
c.close();

// Create unique pairs:
pairs = [];
for(var index = 0; index < ulist.length; index++) {
    var first = ulist[index];
    for(var p2 = index+1; p2 < ulist.length; p2++) {
        pairs.push([first, ulist[p2]]);
    }
}

// And now go get 'em:
pairs.forEach(function(qq) {
    n=db.foo.find({"authors": {$all: qq }}).count();
    print(qq[0] + "-" + qq[1] + ": " + n);
    });
```